# adding tick marks to nouislider jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, nouislider

I'm using noUIslider (http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) in one of my projects. I want to know how I can place tick marks below each value on the slider. 
This is how the slider is initialized:

```
$slider.noUiSlider({
    'start': start,
    'connect': 'lower',
    'orientation': 'horizontal',
    'range': {
        'min': min,
        'max': max
    },                    
    'step': 1,
    'serialization': {
        'format': {
            'decimals': 0
        }
    }
});
```

If anyone of you knows how to add tick marks to this slider it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the plugin does not have such provision to add tickmarks. If you can consider using an another plugin which has such features, I can provide the link to that plugin

Comment: @Rahul please provide link. Thank you

Comment: Should I add it as an answer ? will you accept it ?

Comment: Here is the new plugin link: http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/

Answer (score 1):

noUiSlider now offers this feature. Have a look at the [Pips add-on](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/pips/).

(*disclosure*: I'm the plugin author).